# Respond to Dialogflow with Firestore queried Information

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es

Trying to make my code cleaner by separating out queries for data into different functions and then calling them to give me the response text for Dialogflow. Basically, I can call into firestore and pull back the list, but unless I put the response in the .then() I am confused how to modularize it.

Example:

```
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest((request,response) => {
var listOfClasses = loadClassList().then(
//respond to the user
)};



function loadClassList() {
  var dbRef = db.collection('playerCharacters');
  var getClass = dbRef.get()
  .then(
  //do stuff with the queried data
  ) 
};
```

However, I know I cannot do a .then() on regular function...so is there a way to do this without having to put all of the queries in the main export?

Thanks!

Comment: What? `var loadClassList() {` ?!?

Comment: oops, meant:
      function loadClassList() {

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
  return getClass;
```

form the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `loadClassList()` need to return a Promise (which is what has the `.then()` method that will be called when there is data) instead of actually returning the result.

So if you wanted the data out of the document at that reference, you might do something like this:

```
function loadClassList() {
  var dbRef = db.collection('playerCharacters');
  return dbRef.get()
    .then( querySnapshot => {
      var docData = querySnapshot.docs.map( docSnapshot => docSnapshot.data() );
      return docData;
    });
};
```

This will return a Promise that will eventually resolve to the data from the `playerCharacters` collection.